# helm init Error: error installing: deployments.extensions is forbidden when run inside gitlab runner

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner, kubernetes-helm

I have Gitlab (11.8.1) (self-hosted) connected to self-hosted K8s Cluster (1.13.4). There're 3 projects in gitlab name `shipment`, `authentication_service` and `shipment_mobile_service`.

All projects add the same K8s configuration exception project namespace.

The first project is successful when install Helm Tiller and Gitlab Runner in Gitlab UI.

The second and third projects only install Helm Tiller success, Gitlab Runner error with log in install runner pod:

```
 Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3", GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: cannot connect to Tiller
+ sleep 1s
+ echo 'Retrying (30)...'
+ helm repo add runner https://charts.gitlab.io
Retrying (30)...
"runner" has been added to your repositories
+ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "runner" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈ 
+ helm upgrade runner runner/gitlab-runner --install --reset-values --tls --tls-ca-cert /data/helm/runner/config/ca.pem --tls-cert /data/helm/runner/config/cert.pem --tls-key /data/helm/runner/config/key.pem --version 0.2.0 --set 'rbac.create=true,rbac.enabled=true' --namespace gitlab-managed-apps -f /data/helm/runner/config/values.yaml
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

I don't config gitlab-ci with K8s cluster on first project, only setup for the second and third. The weird thing is with the same `helm-data` (only different by name), the second run success but the third is not.

And because there only one gitlab runner available (from the first project), I assign both 2nd and 3rd project to this runner.

I use this gitlab-ci.yml for both 2 projects with only different name in helm upgrade command.

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: dockerhub.linhnh.vn/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
  CONTAINER_IMAGE_LATEST: dockerhub.linhnh.vn/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest
  CI_REGISTRY: dockerhub.linhnh.vn
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375 # required when use dind

# test phase and build phase using docker:dind success

deploy_beta:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine/helm
  script:
    - echo "Deploy test start ..."
    - helm init --upgrade
    - helm upgrade --install --force shipment-mobile-service --recreate-pods --set image.tag=${CI_PIPELINE_ID} ./helm-data
    - echo "Deploy test completed!"
  environment:
    name: staging
  tags: ["kubernetes_beta"]
  only:
  - master
```

The helm-data is very simple so I think don't really need to paste here.
Here is the log when second project deploy success:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.7.0 (8bb608ff)
  on runner-gitlab-runner-6c8555c86b-gjt9f XrmajZY2
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
Using Kubernetes executor with image linkyard/docker-helm ...
Waiting for pod gitlab-managed-apps/runner-xrmajzy2-project-15-concurrent-0x2bms to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-managed-apps/runner-xrmajzy2-project-15-concurrent-0x2bms to be running, status is Pending
Running on runner-xrmajzy2-project-15-concurrent-0x2bms via runner-gitlab-runner-6c8555c86b-gjt9f...
Cloning into '/root/authentication_service'...
Cloning repository...
Checking out 5068bf1f as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "Deploy start ...."
Deploy start ....
$ helm init --upgrade --dry-run --debug
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: helm
    name: tiller
  name: tiller-deploy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: helm
        name: tiller
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: TILLER_NAMESPACE
          value: kube-system
        - name: TILLER_HISTORY_MAX
          value: "0"
        image: gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.13.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /liveness
            port: 44135
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: tiller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 44134
          name: tiller
        - containerPort: 44135
          name: http
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /readiness
            port: 44135
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources: {}
status: {}

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: helm
    name: tiller
  name: tiller-deploy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tiller
    port: 44134
    targetPort: tiller
  selector:
    app: helm
    name: tiller
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

...
$ helm upgrade --install --force authentication-service --recreate-pods --set image.tag=${CI_PIPELINE_ID} ./helm-data
WARNING: Namespace "gitlab-managed-apps" doesn't match with previous. Release will be deployed to default
Release "authentication-service" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Mar 26 05:27:51 2019
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/Deployment
NAME                    READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
authentication-service  1/1    1           1          17d

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                                    READY  STATUS       RESTARTS  AGE
authentication-service-966c997c4-mglrb  0/1    Pending      0         0s
authentication-service-966c997c4-wzrkj  1/1    Terminating  0         49m

==> v1/Service
NAME                    TYPE      CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)       AGE
authentication-service  NodePort  10.108.64.133  <none>       80:31340/TCP  17d


NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export NODE_PORT=$(kubectl get --namespace default -o jsonpath="{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}" services authentication-service)
  echo http://$NODE_IP:$NODE_PORT
$ echo "Deploy completed"
Deploy completed
Job succeeded
```

And the third project fail:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.7.0 (8bb608ff)
  on runner-gitlab-runner-6c8555c86b-gjt9f XrmajZY2
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
Using Kubernetes executor with image alpine/helm ...
Waiting for pod gitlab-managed-apps/runner-xrmajzy2-project-18-concurrent-0bv4bx to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-managed-apps/runner-xrmajzy2-project-18-concurrent-0bv4bx to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-managed-apps/runner-xrmajzy2-project-18-concurrent-0bv4bx to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-managed-apps/runner-xrmajzy2-project-18-concurrent-0bv4bx to be running, status is Pending
Running on runner-xrmajzy2-project-18-concurrent-0bv4bx via runner-gitlab-runner-6c8555c86b-gjt9f...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/canhnv5/shipmentmobile'...
Checking out 278cbd3d as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "Deploy test start ..."
Deploy test start ...
$ helm init --upgrade
Creating /root/.helm 
Creating /root/.helm/repository 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /root/.helm/plugins 
Creating /root/.helm/starters 
Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts 
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /root/.helm.
Error: error installing: deployments.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:shipment-mobile-service:shipment-mobile-service-service-account" cannot create resource "deployments" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "kube-system"
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

I could see they use the same runner `XrmajZY2` that I install in the first project, same k8s namespace `gitlab-managed-apps`.

I think they use privilege mode but don't know why the second can get the right permission, and the third can not? Should I create user `system:serviceaccount:shipment-mobile-service:shipment-mobile-service-service-account` and assign to cluster-admin?

Thanks to @cookiedough's instruction. I do these steps:

- Fork the `canhv5/shipment-mobile-service` into my root account `root/shipment-mobile-service`.
- Delete `gitlab-managed-apps` namespace without anything inside, run `kubectl delete -f gitlab-admin-service-account.yaml`.
- Apply this file then get the token as @cookiedough guide.
- Back to `root/shipment-mobile-service` in Gitlab, Remove previous Cluster. Add Cluster back with new token. Install Helm Tiller then Gitlab Runner in Gitlab UI.
- Re run the job then the magic happens. But I still unclear why `canhv5/shipment-mobile-service` still get the same error.

Comment: Have you already created the `gitlab-admin` serviceaccount?

Comment: Instead of that token use the one I mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do the following, delete the `gitlab-managed-apps` namespace:

```
kubectl delete namespace gitlab-managed-apps
```

Reciting from the [GitLab tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/) you will need to create a `serviceaccount` and `clusterrolebinding` got GitLab, and you will need the secret created as a result to connect your project to your cluster as a result.

> Create a file called gitlab-admin-service-account.yaml with contents:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: ServiceAccount
 metadata:
   name: gitlab-admin
   namespace: kube-system
 ---
 apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: ClusterRoleBinding
 metadata:
   name: gitlab-admin
 roleRef:
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: ClusterRole
   name: cluster-admin
 subjects:
 - kind: ServiceAccount
   name: gitlab-admin
   namespace: kube-system
```

> Apply the service account and cluster role binding to your cluster:

```
kubectl apply -f gitlab-admin-service-account.yaml
```

> Output:

```
 serviceaccount "gitlab-admin" created
 clusterrolebinding "gitlab-admin" created
```

> Retrieve the token for the gitlab-admin service account:

```
 kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep gitlab-admin | awk '{print $1}')
```

**Copy the `<authentication_token>` value from the output:**

```
Name:         gitlab-admin-token-b5zv4
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name=gitlab-admin
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid=bcfe66ac-39be-11e8-97e8-026dce96b6e8

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1025 bytes
namespace:  11 bytes
token:      <authentication_token>
```

Follow this tutorial to connect your cluster to the project, otherwise you will have to stitch up the same thing along the way with a lot more pain!

Comment: If `gitlab-admin` is used to connect Gitlab to Cluster, so I have another service account named `default-token` inside `gitlab-managed-apps` namespace that Gitlab use to connect to Cluster. I also install Helm Tiller and a Gitlab Runner successful with it.

Comment: Yes, they will both likely work for those installations. But try the connection with this token, and try installing the Runner and Tiller with this one.

Comment: Yes, I've just tried. Create `gitlab-admin` service account, grab token, change token Cluster Info in Gitlab project. Then try to install Gitlab Runner but still error like above. 
Try to re-run the job but still get the forbidden with `shipment-mobile-service` service account.
Then I delete current Cluster in third project, add new Cluster, then install Helm Tiller (success), install Gitlab Runner (fail) and try re run job but fail again.
All the errors are the same with my first post :(

Comment: Before you re-attach the cluster to the project, delete the `gitlab-managed-apps` namespace, once you do, maybe try creating the serviceaccount for `shipment-mobile-service`.

Comment: It seems serious, because I really don't know how Helm Tiller and Gitlab Runner work together. I will try tomorrow after take a backup plan.

Comment: I takes these steps:

1. Remove everything in `gitlab-managed-apps`.

2. Back to Gitlab UI in `shipment-mobile-service` project, remove current Cluster then add it back, install Helm Tiller then Gitlab Runner successful. I can see `gitlab-managed-apps` with `tiller-deploy` and `gitlab-runner` pod come back.

3. Change the Runner in both shipment-mobile and authentication project to new Runner.

4. Run again deploy stage and get the same result:

- `authentication-service` still success.

- `shipment-mobile-service` still forbidden.

Comment: Delete the namespace instead of everything inside of it. When you are adding the cluster back, use the tutorial I linked above, so you will be adding the serviceaccount and using the token from that. Once you add it back, the namespace will be created again and you will need the new token.

Comment: I already create `gitlab-admin` in previous post, so I will delete `gitlab-admin`, delete `gitlab-managed-apps` namespace. Then follow your instruction. Install Helm Tiller and Gitlab Runner success inside Gitlab UI in `shipment-mobile-service` project. Then assign Runner, now they work fine, both two projects.
Could you please explain what happen?

Comment: I take that as it is working now, right? So what you were doing before was trying to install your deployments through the token that was created in the namespace `gitlab-managed-apps` but this token is limited to its own namespace, I'm assuming you wanted to deploy things in the other namespaces, so you will have to create the `gitlab-admin` serviceaccount and clusterrolebinding and use the new token that has admin permissions, now you can create resources in all namespaces.

Comment: Yes, I fork the second project to my own gitlab account then it error then it works fine after follow your step. But now I come back to second project in canhv5 gitlab account, assign new Runner that I created in fork Gitlab UI, still got error like before.

Comment: The problem with GitLab is that they don't have an official process for multiple groups using the same cluster. So what you need to do in order to connect multiple projects is either use `group-level` connection or delete the namespace every time and do the same thing. If you delete the namespace every time, your previous projects are going to be fine once you connect the new project.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the different between my fork `root/shipment_mobile_service` and `canhv5/shipment_mobile_service` project? My fork work fine, but the `canhv5` still got the error.

Comment: Not sure about that, sorry.

Comment: where to create gitlab-admin-service-account.yaml ?